# Angular aside modal window with form. The form is being submitted when i cancel\close the window

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I am using angular aside to create a modal window. In the modal window there is a form with a submit button and a close button.

If I fill out the form and submit it and then click the close button the form is being submitted again. If I dont fill out the form and just click the close button the modal window is being closed with out the form is being submitted.

Any idea on how to prevent the form submit when closing the window?

Here is my controller where i have the method to open the modal window:

```
mainApp2.controller("mainAppController", ["$scope", "$aside", "$document", function ($scope, $aside) {
var asideInstance;
$scope.openSidebar = function () {
    asideInstance = $aside.open({
        templateUrl: "/Apps/Modules/ModuleConfigForm/templates/moduleConfigformTemplate.html",
        controller: "moduleConfigformController",
        placement: "left",
        size: "sm",
        backdrop: true
    });
}
}])
```

Here is my comtroller with the close logic

```
mainApp2.controller("moduleConfigformController",
function moduleConfigformController($scope, $http, moduleConfigformService, $uibModalInstance, $filter) {
    $scope.close = function (e) {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
        e.stopPropagation();
    };
....
}
```

Here is my form:

```
<form name="configForm" ng-submit="submitConfigForm()">
        <button ng-disabled: ng-disabled="configForm.$invalid" tabindex="100" class="btn btn-success pull-left" type="submit" ng-class="{'btn-primary':configForm.$valid}">Start</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning pull-right" ng-click="close()">Close window</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Be careful when using buttons without a type attribute, since browsers will consider them as the default submit button of a form.

Try adding `type` attribute to `button` as shown below to prevent the form submission

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" ng-click="close()">Close window</button>
```

Comment: Thank you Jannu. It worked. Of course i needed the type. I did not see it was missing. Thanks again :-)